# RTL does to not order checkbox well

Tags: laravel, npm, localization, bootstrap-5, direction

I have a Laravel project with bootstrap ui, the project is localized with

```php
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}" dir="{{ LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocaleDirection() }}">
```

so it accepts to directions depends on the language, but when I added `--auth` scaffolding with Laravel, the `checkbox` in

```php
                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('app.rememberMe') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

is to the left in all ways, like this:
[An image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw5Rz.png)

I tried to reorder the label before the checkbox, but it didn't help

Note that I'm using compiled bootstrap with npm, and CDN for RTL bootstrap.
I thought bootstrap's classes would be overridden by one of them, but both of them added the functionality for both direction at the same time, like this for `me` (margin start)
[example for margin start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Opq.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's might happed because overlapping with this class "form-check" in bootstrap try to remove this class to "form-control" like this :

```html
 <div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
        <div class="form-control">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                {{ __('app.rememberMe') }}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```